# Java ClassLoader VM Arguments

Tags: java, jvm, arguments, executable-jar, jvm-arguments

The code below attempts to launch an external executable JAR file.

```
final File file = new File("/path/to/executable.jar");
JarFile jarFile = null;
jarFile = new JarFile(file);
final Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
final URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { file.toURI().toURL() }, Launcher.class.getClassLoader());
final Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("com.example.launcher.Launcher", true, child);
final Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
final Object[] arguments = { new String[0] };
        method.invoke(null, arguments);
jarfile.close();
```

Arguments that the main method receives can be set in the `Object[] arguments` but how would one set VM arguments, such as `-XstartOnFirstThread`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set JVM arguments you have to start a JVM. Your current code will run the main method in the JVM that's already running.

To start a JVM it's probably easiest to run the `java` command using `ProcessBuilder`.